# Alternative wordings for a "Skip" button?

Tags: buttons, labels

The product owner for a survey app I've been working on wants the "Skip" buttons we've implemented for each question to use "less harsh" language. What other labels can I use? I've considered "Not applicable" or "N/A" but I can't think of much else.

Comment: http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/skip?s=t for the "Avoid" term

Comment: Please provide more context for the "Skip" button. Are there other buttons? What are the other response options? And in what format? Buttons? Links? Multiple choices responses?

Comment: No other buttons except the responses to each survey question. The responses are just a scale from 1-10.

Comment: None of the terms in the thesaurus sound very good lol which is why I'm asking this

Comment: To be honest, "skip" seems about as un-harsh as it gets; it's short, relatively informal, and commonly-used, which means its function will be recognisable to many people who've filled in a web survey before. Have you asked the product owner what _they'd_ consider to be "less harsh"?

Answer (score 2):

- later
- maybe later
- Go to next xxx (item, page, question, step)
- Let's move on
- No answer
- I don't want to answer this one

Answer (score 1):

- **Not now**
- **Let me come back to this**
- **No thanks**
- **Let me skip this one**

are terms that spring to mind.  Of course, it depends how much screen space you have and the language you're using in the rest of the web site.